Get subfolders and files in a Box repository thru API and Apps Script
I'm trying to get the following in a Box folder with ID=1234567:

All subfolders and files (including files in the subfolders) of a particular folder
The name, URL and full folder path of each subfolder and file (ex. My folder\Family\Picture.jpeg where "My folder" is the one with ID=1234567)

I came upon this blog that provided a great starting point. Upon modifying the script, I was able to extract the item names and subfolders within "My folder", but I'm not able to extract their URL, full folder path, and files within the different subfolders.
Here is part of the code where I've been having a headache:
function getFilesAndFolders() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/1234567/items?fields=name,type', {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + getBoxService_().getAccessToken(),
    },
  });

  var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var items = result.entries;

  var filesAndFolders = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      filesAndFolders.push({ name: items[i].name, type:items[i].type, url:items[i].shared_link.url});
  }

  Logger.log(filesAndFolders);
}

In this resource, I saw this shared_link object that has the url field, but the script throws an error when I do items[i].shared_link.url. Also, I have no idea where to start with the full folder path. I saw this path_collection object but it doesn't seem to have the field I need.
Any help is appreciated.
Edit:
I was able to determine the URL via the ID since it's simply a simple structure like: https://xxx.app.box.com/folder/id. What I'm struggling with now is how to go thru the subfolders. Hoping someone can pitch in their ideas.

The actual resource returned would be https://developer.box.com/reference/get-folders-id-items/

There's also a readymade code for transversing folders here: https://developer.box.com/guides/folders/bulk/build-folder-tree/ However, it needs to be adapted  to Apps script(as the SKU  isn't directly supported).
